# old viewcontrollers still visible in the background

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

In my app, the user starts at a registration/login screen where the user enters an email and if it is valid, the user is redirected to the main menu. In the main menu there are a few buttons that takes the user to different views but my problem is that when the user goes to one of these views, the login screen is shown in the background.

when the user clicks the login button, a 3rd party sdk is starting a process of setting up an endpoint for handling bluetooth keys. If this is done successfully I redirect the user to the main menu. The views that the user goes to from the main menu has a a background image added with insertSubview at index 0 which ends up behind the login screen.

how the user is redirected from login page to main menu:

```
func redirectTo(storyBoardId: String) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryBoardId(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIndentifier: 
    storyBoardId) as UIViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = view
    if let navigationController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? 
    UINavigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Code for clicking one of the buttons on the main menu:

```
@IBAction func keysButtonClikc(_ sender: Any) {
    letvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "keyViewId")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
}
```

So, I have tried to completely remove the login viewcontroller so that it does not show up in the background by trying to make the mainMenu as the new root and removing the loginviewcontroller by popToRootViewController but it does not go away.

Comment: You're instantiating `"Main"` as a `UIViewController` and setting it as the `.rootViewController` ... but then you're treating it as a `UINavigationController`? That looks problematic to begin with... is "Main" a navigation controller?

Comment: Did you fix the issue?